# Can I paralellize tiny sub-10ms tasks? (e.g. matrix inversion)

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, thread-priority

I have a general question about threads (or fibers) on Windows and Linux, in any programming language:

Is it possible to have a "2nd thread standing by" and have it quickly jump into action and help with a small task for a few milliseconds, without getting pre-empted?
I should add that I am hoping for legible code without mutexes and spin locks.

To show that conventional thread pools do not work for small tasks, consider a matrix inversion problem in C#.
I am using Ivan Kuckir's [matrix class](http://www.ivank.net/blogspot/matrix_cs/Matrix.cs).
I copy his Invert function and call it InvertParallel as follows:

```cs
public Matrix InvertParallel()   // modified from Ivan's Invert(), see link above
{
    if (L == null) MakeLU();
    Matrix inv = new Matrix(rows, cols);
    Parallel.ForEach<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, rows), rowID =>
    {
        Matrix Ei = Matrix.ZeroMatrix(rows, 1);
        Ei[rowID, 0] = 1;
        Matrix col = SolveWith(Ei);
        inv.SetCol(col, rowID);
    });
    return inv;
}
```

Then I invoke both Invert and Invert_Parallel functions and measure time it takes:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start();
    Matrix A = Matrix.IdentityMatrix(50, 50);
    Matrix I1 = A.Invert();
    long elapsed1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Matrix I2 = A.InvertParallel();
    long elapsed2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed1;
    Console.WriteLine("Matrix size=" + A.rows + ", Invert=" + elapsed1 + "ms, Invert_Parallel=" + elapsed2 + "ms");
}
```

The fairly obvious results show that for small tasks (matrix size 50), launching tasks from a thread pool is slower than running single-threaded:

```
Matrix size=50,  Invert=  5ms,  InvertParallel=21ms
Matrix size=100, Invert= 19ms,  InvertParallel=24ms
Matrix size=200, Invert=137ms,  InvertParallel=44ms
```

(Apologies - I had to remove all links from the notes below, as I am a new poster)

P.S. possibly related S/O articles: 'how to start two threads at the same time',  'Linux - threads and process scheduling priorities'

P.S. Yes I know there is a more clever algorithm for calculating the inverse, which scales as O(N^2.376).

P.P.S. I am not familiar with User-Mode Scheduling (UMS on Windows) [User-Mode Scheduling ('UMS' on Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd627187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), can it help?

Comment: "can I" - definitely. "Should I" - good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing tasks between threads, especially those which have a significant amount of data associated with them has a non-trivial overhead which can result in slower performance for small tasks as you have seen.  You need to find the sweet spot where using more than one core is faster.

BTW you can get a small improvement by making one of the worker threads, the current thread saving one context switch and copies between caches. e.g. if you have 8 cores, pass 1/7 to 7 other threads and do 1/8 in the current thread.

Comment: Peter - could you maybe explain where the problem is?  5ms seems a very, very long time to me - much longer than things like context-switches.  Why is the pool so slow in this case?  What is it doing for 21-5=16ms?  Queueing a matrix object in C# should be just a reference push, yes?  What is going on here?  Why is the invert so inefficent?

Comment: The reference push and the context switch (to wake the thread) is likely to be about 10 micro-seconds in Java (and much the same in C# I assume)  The push of data from one cache to another depends on the size of the data and can take milli-seconds if there is enough activity.

Comment: Peter was correct. waking a second thread is very quick. The problem with my code above is that I did not prime the thread pool. If you prime the thread pool, you get this result: `Matrix size=50, Invert=5ms, Invert_Parallel=2ms`